# Keystrokes buffering on Neovim when rotating the screen with xrandr on Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm

Tags: x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alacritty

I got a very odd behaviour on a niche configuration.

I'm using Raspberry Pi OS Lite Bookworm on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2.
I've configured X11 with Qtile as a Windows manager, Alacritty as terminal and Neovim 0.9.5 with NvChad customisation as IDE.
And to add to the nichest niche niche, I use a 7.9inch display from Waveshare (400x1280).

I got a "buffering" issue when I type in INSERT mode on Neovim.

I'll explain: When I'm entering INSERT mode in Neovim, the first stroke on my keyboard print the caracter on screen, my second stroke do nothing, the third stroke print the second stroke, the fourth the caracter from the third, and so on until I hit Esc, then the last stroke is printed.
And it only happen on the first two lines of any files !
Editing lines below doesn't have this buffering problem.

I've tried to locate the origine of the issue with cross-testing:

- Neovim: Tried on nano, doesn't reproduce. Tried Vim, doesn't reproduce. Tried Neovim v0.9.0, reproduce.
- NvChad: Tried a neovim from scratch (deleted `~/.config/nvim`, `~/.local/share/nvim` and `~/.local/state/nvim`), doesn't reproduce. Tried a minimal Lazy.nvim config, reproduce --> Might be a component from Lazy.nvim UI that cause this behaviour.
- Alacritty: Tried on Xterm, doesn't reproduce --> Might be a probel with alacritty rendering process
- Qtile: Tried with xfce, reproduce
- X11: Launching nvim from tty or on ssh (so without active X session), doesn't reproduce. Wasn't able to launch Qtile with Wayland on the rapsberry (can't install pywayland)
- Raspberry Pi Os bookworm: Was previously on Bullseye 32bits and didn't have the issue. It happend when I made a fresh install to upgrade to Bookworm 64bits. At the time I commented out the line "dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-V3D", but on Bookworm X11 can't start without it.

**But, I've discovered that it happen only when I rotate my screen in the X session.**
My .xinitrc looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Rotate screen
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate right

# Start Qtile Window Manager
exec $HOME/.local/bin/qtile start
```

If I comment the `xrandr` command to rotate the screen, the issue doesn't happen.

When in my X session, If I rotate 180° with xrandr, I don't reproduce. But if I rotate 90° or 270°, the problem happen again... I'm clueless...

I'm a bit stuck in my research, I'll appreciate any help.